# Having trouble expanding Bootstrap Navigator across my <header>

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

The header in my site is not fully expanding horizontally across my header section of my site.

e.g - There is a blank space open towards the right of my nav embedded within my header section.

I have

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Bootstrap Test</title>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Custom CSS -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />

    <!--

        main.css file contents attached from above ^

        .right {
            padding-left: 850px;
        }

        .title {
            padding-left: 0px;
        }

        .main {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .vr {
            border-right: 1px solid;
        }

        /* .navbar {
            background-color: 'purple';
            width: 100%;
        } */

        header {
            width: 100%;
        }

    -->


    </head>
    <body>

    <!--  -------------------------------------------------------  -->
  
        <!-- This is the part I am struggling with...
             In here, the navigation bar within the header
             section is extending only about 90% across
             and not 100%. -->

        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
                <h2 class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lockerroom Buzz</h2>
            </nav>
        </header>

    <!--  -------------------------------------------------------  -->

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-2 vr">
                <h1>First Column</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-8 vr">
                <h1>Main Column</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel nisi eget sapien porttitor cursus in mattis augue. Donec aliquam consectetur quam. Sed posuere augue vitae aliquet egestas. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec eu mi sed felis ultricies volutpat vitae vel magna. Nunc varius tristique dui, ut euismod ex euismod ac. Sed non accumsan dolor. Sed ut elit lobortis, suscipit eros a, finibus velit. In vulputate, massa nec egestas posuere, nunc orci euismod metus, sit amet fringilla sapien magna at purus. Pellentesque enim massa, pellentesque ut velit eget, scelerisque rutrum lorem. In tempus suscipit accumsan. Sed id aliquet arcu, ullamcorper luctus nunc. Duis id tortor finibus, viverra quam ut, consequat nisl. Etiam condimentum diam nec nulla placerat, non egestas tellus aliquam. Pellentesque suscipit, nisl a vulputate hendrerit, leo nunc varius sem, a interdum lectus tortor nec mauris.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel nisi eget sapien porttitor cursus in mattis augue. Donec aliquam consectetur quam. Sed posuere augue vitae aliquet egestas. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec eu mi sed felis ultricies volutpat vitae vel magna. Nunc varius tristique dui, ut euismod ex euismod ac. Sed non accumsan dolor. Sed ut elit lobortis, suscipit eros a, finibus velit. In vulputate, massa nec egestas posuere, nunc orci euismod metus, sit amet fringilla sapien magna at purus. Pellentesque enim massa, pellentesque ut velit eget, scelerisque rutrum lorem. In tempus suscipit accumsan. Sed id aliquet arcu, ullamcorper luctus nunc. Duis id tortor finibus, viverra quam ut, consequat nisl. Etiam condimentum diam nec nulla placerat, non egestas tellus aliquam. Pellentesque suscipit, nisl a vulputate hendrerit, leo nunc varius sem, a interdum lectus tortor nec mauris.</p>

                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel nisi eget sapien porttitor cursus in mattis augue. Donec aliquam consectetur quam. Sed posuere augue vitae aliquet egestas. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec eu mi sed felis ultricies volutpat vitae vel magna. Nunc varius tristique dui, ut euismod ex euismod ac. Sed non accumsan dolor. Sed ut elit lobortis, suscipit eros a, finibus velit. In vulputate, massa nec egestas posuere, nunc orci euismod metus, sit amet fringilla sapien magna at purus. Pellentesque enim massa, pellentesque ut velit eget, scelerisque rutrum lorem. In tempus suscipit accumsan. Sed id aliquet arcu, ullamcorper luctus nunc. Duis id tortor finibus, viverra quam ut, consequat nisl. Etiam condimentum diam nec nulla placerat, non egestas tellus aliquam. Pellentesque suscipit, nisl a vulputate hendrerit, leo nunc varius sem, a interdum lectus tortor nec mauris.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-2">
                <h1>Last Column</h1>
            </div>

        </div>

        <footer>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-bottom">Footer</nav>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Expected: 100% horizontal expansion. No horizontal scrolling

Actual: 90% horizontal expansion. Horizontal scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Reason is you are using `class = "row"` without any `container` which is giving `margin-left:-15px; margin-right:-15px` causing the horizantal scrolling 
so add `<div class="row">` inside a `<div class="container">`

i have added that and attached the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap Test</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./css/main.css" />

<!--

    main.css file contents attached from above ^

    .right {
        padding-left: 850px;
    }

    .title {
        padding-left: 0px;
    }

    .main {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .vr {
        border-right: 1px solid;
    }

    /* .navbar {
        background-color: 'purple';
        width: 100%;
    } */

    header {
        width: 100%;
    }

-->


</head>
<body>

<!--  -------------------------------------------------------  -->

    <!-- This is the part I am struggling with...
         In here, the navigation bar within the header
         section is extending only about 90% across
         and not 100%. -->

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top">
            <h2 class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lockerroom Buzz</h2>
        </nav>
    </header>

<!--  -------------------------------------------------------  -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-2 vr">
            <h1>First Column</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 vr">
            <h1>Main Column</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel nisi eget sapien porttitor cursus in mattis augue. Donec aliquam consectetur quam. Sed posuere augue vitae aliquet egestas. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec eu mi sed felis ultricies volutpat vitae vel magna. Nunc varius tristique dui, ut euismod ex euismod ac. Sed non accumsan dolor. Sed ut elit lobortis, suscipit eros a, finibus velit. In vulputate, massa nec egestas posuere, nunc orci euismod metus, sit amet fringilla sapien magna at purus. Pellentesque enim massa, pellentesque ut velit eget, scelerisque rutrum lorem. In tempus suscipit accumsan. Sed id aliquet arcu, ullamcorper luctus nunc. Duis id tortor finibus, viverra quam ut, consequat nisl. Etiam condimentum diam nec nulla placerat, non egestas tellus aliquam. Pellentesque suscipit, nisl a vulputate hendrerit, leo nunc varius sem, a interdum lectus tortor nec mauris.</p>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel nisi eget sapien porttitor cursus in mattis augue. Donec aliquam consectetur quam. Sed posuere augue vitae aliquet egestas. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec eu mi sed felis ultricies volutpat vitae vel magna. Nunc varius tristique dui, ut euismod ex euismod ac. Sed non accumsan dolor. Sed ut elit lobortis, suscipit eros a, finibus velit. In vulputate, massa nec egestas posuere, nunc orci euismod metus, sit amet fringilla sapien magna at purus. Pellentesque enim massa, pellentesque ut velit eget, scelerisque rutrum lorem. In tempus suscipit accumsan. Sed id aliquet arcu, ullamcorper luctus nunc. Duis id tortor finibus, viverra quam ut, consequat nisl. Etiam condimentum diam nec nulla placerat, non egestas tellus aliquam. Pellentesque suscipit, nisl a vulputate hendrerit, leo nunc varius sem, a interdum lectus tortor nec mauris.</p>

            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce vel nisi eget sapien porttitor cursus in mattis augue. Donec aliquam consectetur quam. Sed posuere augue vitae aliquet egestas. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec eu mi sed felis ultricies volutpat vitae vel magna. Nunc varius tristique dui, ut euismod ex euismod ac. Sed non accumsan dolor. Sed ut elit lobortis, suscipit eros a, finibus velit. In vulputate, massa nec egestas posuere, nunc orci euismod metus, sit amet fringilla sapien magna at purus. Pellentesque enim massa, pellentesque ut velit eget, scelerisque rutrum lorem. In tempus suscipit accumsan. Sed id aliquet arcu, ullamcorper luctus nunc. Duis id tortor finibus, viverra quam ut, consequat nisl. Etiam condimentum diam nec nulla placerat, non egestas tellus aliquam. Pellentesque suscipit, nisl a vulputate hendrerit, leo nunc varius sem, a interdum lectus tortor nec mauris.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h1>Last Column</h1>
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>

    <footer>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-bottom">Footer</nav>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. It fixed the issue